# Automatically enter values in an excel sheet from another excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am using Excel 2007. I have two Excel sheets (lets say A and B). I want to automatically input values (in particular cells) from sheet A to sheet B.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to macro, using the macro recording facility can help you get a grasp of how it works. Simply start it, then do the copy-paste operations manually, then stop and look at the produced macro.

The code is usually ugly, but the operations you need being simple copy/paste, it shouldn't be a problem to understand, adapt and clean it up.

On the other hand, if you want values in sheet B to update in real-time from sheet A, you can also use formulas to refer to sheet A. Just select your destination cell, edit it and start a formula by typing `=`, then go to sheet A, select the source cell and press enter. This way you'll see the syntax used to reference cells in other sheets/workbooks.